# Solr Query - How to fix not expected result (maybe culture specific)?

Tags: solr, sitecore, solrnet

I switched the search provider from Lucene to Solr in my Sitecore application. There are some additions from Sitecore to the `schema.xml` from Solr. I am using Solr 6.6.3.
The change was successful, but some search results are not like before.

**Example:**

> ```
> Search for German word "Trommelfilter" won't return any results.
> Search for German word "Trommelfilt" returns the expected result.
> ```

It seems that `"er"` is maybe removed internally.
Maybe some culture specific issue?

I run the search again in Solr directly, but the problem is still there.

*Solr Query 1:*
`searchcontent_t_de:(*Trommelfilt*)`

*Result:*

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"searchcontent_t_de:(*trommelfilt*)",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1554983614349"}},
  "response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

*Solr Query 2:*
`searchcontent_t_de:(*Trommelfilter*)`

*Result:*

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":8,
    "params":{
      "q":"searchcontent_t_de:(*Trommelfilt*)",
      "indent":"on",
      "wt":"json",
      "_":"1554983656940"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        ...
        "_templatename":"Application",
        "culture_s":"de-DE",
        "_database":"master",
        "searchcontent_t_de":"... einen Trommelfilter gereinigt. ...",
        "_language":"de-DE",
        ...
}}
```

The below is the configured schema in Solr for the affected core, the configuration for `searchcontent_t_de` is done through the `dynamicField`.

```
<dynamicField name="*_t_de" type="text_de" indexed="true" stored="true" />
...
<fieldType name="text_de" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
        <filter class="solr.GermanNormalizationFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.GermanLightStemFilterFactory" />
        <!-- less aggressive: <filter class="solr.GermanMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
        <!-- more aggressive: <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="German2"/> -->
      </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I want to know which change I have to do to have the expected result (the entire word should be found).

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard searches won't perform any of the steps for the configured analysis chain - when you're using wildcards (`*`), those are skipped.

This is also why you don't get a hit, since there's a stemming filter present when the tokens are stored - this removes the `er` ending from the stored token.

With wildcard: In index: `trommelfilt` - in search: `*trommelfilter*`. These doesn't match - since the stored token doesn't have `er`, and no removal takes place when there are wildcards, so no match is generated.

If you drop the wildcards (i.e. search for just `trommelfilter`) you'll get a hit, as the same processing happens both when indexing and querying. The query string will be processed to just `trommelfilt` as well, matching the `trommelfilt` token in the index.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.

query: ```searchcontent_t_de:trommelfilter```
also returns no results
query: ```searchcontent_t_de:trommelfilt```
returns the expected result.

does that mean, that the wildcard is not the reason?

Comment: Should I remove the GermanLightStemFilterFactory and reIndex to solve the Problem?

Comment: You can use the Analysis page under your Solr admin page to see how the search and query analysis is performed. That'll tell you exactly why trommelfilter and trommelfilt gives you different results, even without a wildcard.